# 411 Length required error with App Proxies

Tags: shopify

I set up an app proxy for my app deployed on a normal shared hosted server (not Heroku or anything like that). It works like a charm (as do my other apps) until I set the content type to application/liquid.

As soon as I do that I get a 411 Length Required error by nginx which is generated by my server (my guess). I tried to resolve it by setting content length to 0. It worked for a while but then it stopped. I tried other values and it works depending on its mood. Funnily, sometimes the output is truncated at content length, and at times I get the whole output (a simple page refresh can give different outputs). Also, sometimes it doesn't work AT ALL and shopify throws a "we're having tech. difficulties" error.

To summarize, content length is not reliable at all.

Now I am not sure exactly what causes a 411 error and what can I do about it. And why is it thrown only when content type is liquid. Moreover, content-length doesn't result in a consistent output (no output/predictable output/truncated output/shopify error).

Anyone knows what's up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your responses are using [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). I don't think nginx supports this by default, so would return a 411 error in this case because chunked encoding doesn't use a Content-Length header.

If you do want to use chunked responses, there is the http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpChunkinModule module that should add support for this.  Otherwise, disable the chunked encoding in your app, and make sure the Content-Length header is consistent with the length of the body of the response.

Comment: I am gonna give that a try! Thanks!